# MySQL return multiple rows from joined table as columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have 2 tables (shop and opening hours).

I wish to return the shop opening hours as columns rather than separate rows. I've seen a few ideas on Stack but none that I can transpose to my own situation.

```
Stores
------
id
name

Opening Hours
-------------
store_id
dayofweek
openinghh
openingmm
closinghh
closingmm
```

Each store will have 7 entries in the Opening Hours table (one for each day of the week)

The returned row will be

```
store_id | name | Monday Opening | Monday Closing |Tues Opening | Tues Closing etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not so hard :)

```
SELECT s.id as store_id
, s.name as store_name
##
, concat(oh_mon.openinghh, ':', oh_mon.openingmm) as monday_opening
, concat(oh_mon.closeinghh, ':', oh_mon.closeingmm) as monday_closing
##
, concat(oh_tue.openinghh, ':', oh_tue.openingmm) as tuesday_opening
, concat(oh_tue.closeinghh, ':', oh_tue.closeingmm) as tuesday_closing
##
, concat(oh_wed.openinghh, ':', oh_wed.openingmm) as wednesday_opening
, concat(oh_wed.closeinghh, ':', oh_wed.closeingmm) as wednesday_closing
##
FROM stores s
##
LEFT JOIN opening_hours oh_mon
ON oh_mon.store_id = s.id
AND oh_mon.dayofweek = 'Monday'
##
LEFT JOIN opening_hours oh_tue
ON oh_tue.store_id = s.id
AND oh_tue.dayofweek = 'Tuesday'
##
LEFT JOIN opening_hours oh_wed
ON oh_wed.store_id = s.id
AND oh_wed.dayofweek = 'Wednesday'
##
WHERE 1=1
```

and use LEFT JOIN for each day you want to be shown

Comment: Excellent. I did wonder if there was a simpler way. Thank you!

Comment: yes but it depends on your data model ... could you send me an example of your data?